# Visual Studio Code .json file "expected comma" error

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm trying to change some settings in VS code but keep getting an expected comma error. I got this error on one of the lines so I copied it and moved it to the bottom and it sopped giving me an error only to move it down to the next line.

I've tried looking this up but all the answers seem super niche and vs code tells me there is no way to solve it even though they are telling me there is an error

```
{
    "python.pythonPath": "/usr/local/bin/python3",
    "workbench.editorAssociations": [
        {
            "viewType": "jupyter.notebook.ipynb",
            "filenamePattern": "*.ipynb"
        }
    ],
    "files.autoSave": "afterDelay",
    "workbench.iconTheme": "material-icon-theme",
    "editor.fontSize": 17,
    "editor.tabSize": 2,
    "editor.wordWrap": "on",
    "editor.fontLigatures": true,
    "workbench.sideBar.location": "right",
    "window.title": "${activeEditorShort}${separator}${rootName}${rootPath}",
    "tabnine.experimentalAutoImports": true,
    "kite.showWelcomeNotificationOnStartup": false,
    "AREPL.pythonPath": "python3",
    "code-runner.runInTerminal": true,
    "editor.fontFamily": "Fira Code, Menlo, Monaco, 'Courier New', monospace",
    "workbench.colorTheme": "Cobalt2"
    "files.trimTrailingWhitespace": true,
    "editor.fontWeight": "400",
    "prettier.eslintIntegration": true,
    "editor.cursorStyle": "line",
    "editor.cursorWidth": 5,
    "editor.cursorBlinking": "solid",
    "editor.renderWhitespace": "all",
    "editor.lineHeight": 25,
    "editor.letterSpacing": 0.5,
    "editor.semanticHighlighting.enabled": false
}
```

Do not know why the closing "}" showed up at the bottom but it is in my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a comma at the end of line 22 `"workbench.colorTheme": "Cobalt2"`